# A good way to send complex objects with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, json

In my web app, I have some complex objects written with JavaScript (ie nested arrays, objects within objects withing objects, etc) and the nature of my app relies on these. I need to send all the data to PHP so that I can save it to the database. What is an efficient, easy way to send my objects to PHP? I tried JSON, but got strange errors like 'too much recursion', which I'm guessing means that my objects are too complex for it. So is there a good library of script that will do this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

So JSON then. I tried updating the JSON library to no avail, and I am now looking for cyclic references.

Comment: Are the objects cyclic, or otherwise not trees? E.g. A=[B,C], B=[D], C=[D], D=[]. JSON can only represent objects which are trees.

Comment: is there an easy way to find cyclic, or do I have to do it manually? I am guessing manually, right?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection

Comment: @Breton: That article talks about detecting cycles in sequences; not sure it's relevant here.

Comment: Sure it's relevant, but I'll admit its relevency is a bit obscure. Once you've worked out that in order to detect a cycle in a graph, you have to recurse. Then you have a sequence of recursions. Each recursion is examining a value. So it's a sequence of values. Some of those values are javascript objects. Once you get that far the article suddenly starts looking a lot more relevant, because the task is then a matter of looking for repeats in the sequences of javascript objects as you recurse through.

Comment: Breton's comment did help, I found the object that was causing the cycle. Now only to fix it...

Comment: One other thing that might help is that the stringify function in json2.js optionally takes a filter function, or a whitelist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much any JSON library will have a too much recursion error if your object has circular references. The recursion limit of the javascript implementations I've tried is well in excess of ~100 levels deep, so your object would have to be *really* complicated.

You'll want to detect and eliminate circular references before trying to serialise your object using any sort of library.

edit: Just tested the firefox 3.5 and it tops out at 3000 levels of recursion.

Answer (score 5):

JSON *is* the right answer.

I suspect your JSON libraries are either broken or too restrictive.  Check the JSON to see if it's well-formed, and if so, find a better library that can cope with your data structure.

Consider also simplifying the data structure.  It may be too complex for your own good.

Answer (score 1):

I agree- JSON is the answer. I think the error you are encountering may be part of the library you are using...

http://markmail.org/message/2d5lvmdeg2qg55qr

Mentions the same error.

I've used many complex JSON objects and never encountered that error - I'd say something else is at play.

Comment: I tried what your link said, and I still got the same error, sorry.

Comment: Any chance you could post a sample of the data that is causing the error?
You may also want to run the data through a validator to see if it flags anything.
http://www.jsonlint.com/